# Is the phrase "I'm afraid" interchangeable with "I am afraid"?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-usage, contractions

I don't think I've ever seen the phrase/idiom used with the non-contracted "I am". If it's not interchangeable, would it be odd to see that phrase in a poem where there aren't any other contractions? Would it break the consistency?

Comment: Which sense of the phrase?

Comment: Avoiding contractions -- especially first-person contractions -- is a mark of calmness and determination. When one is afraid, these are not the most prominent characteristics displayed.

Comment: I am afraid you haven't read enough.

Comment: @HotLicks Or even that they _have not_ read enough.